# How to use the cookies from the browser in my program? Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, request

I would like to take a table from website, however I need to login in there. When I sign in in the site and get the cookies from there with my program and try to get the table, simply appear a error with html. This error:

"HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
8
9 print(cookies_dictionary)
---> 10 df = pd.read_html('https://exames.genera.com.br/busca-parentes')
11 df

12 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
650
651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"

I tried to get the cookies from the website, but not working unfortunately, here is my code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
a_session = requests.Session()
url = 'https://exames.genera.com.br/busca-parentes'
a_session.get(url)
session_cookies = a_session.cookies
cookies_dictionary = session_cookies.get_dict()

print(cookies_dictionary)
df = pd.read_html(url) #Problem here
df
```

The table that I want to get:
[image: table]

I know that the authenticate cookies is that:

[image: authenticate]

Someone can help me?

Comment: [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) function reads `str, path object or file-like object` containing HTML code, not a link to a resource. You need to make another request to get the table HTML code and supply it to the function.

Comment: How to do this? Because I need sign in the website for see the table.

Comment: perhaps it is rendering the page (in which case you must too with something like Selenium) or provides a useful API for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the **HTTPBasicAuth** from the requests package?

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates
Towards the end of the page it shows how you can pass a username and password to the website you're attempting to access.

You can use http://httpbin.org/#/ to see if you're sending your request correctly.